# Setting zoom in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

In my app I have a mapkit view and right when the app starts it zooms into the users locations`mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.follow, animated: true)`, but when I run this code it zooms into the users location but I want to zoom more closer into the users location. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `regionRadius` according to your needs.

```
let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000
func centerMapOnLocation(_ location: CLLocation) {
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, regionRadius, regionRadius)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}
```

Where `location.coordinate` is the coordinate where you want to zoom in.